# Navigation sidebar with Hakyll

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, haskell, hakyll

I'm trying to make a website with **Hakyll** and **bootstrap**. I would like to add a **navigation sidebar** (automatically updated at compilation) on some pages of my website and I'm not sure of how to do it. I searched for tutorials or examples but I didn't find anything.

According to me, I should render a temporary page from a **sidebar template** and render my page by adding this html code with `$partial()$`. I also read about making `snapshots`.

But I'm not comfortable with Hakyll functions and I don't know how to do it?

**Do you know how to make a navigation sidebar with hakyll ?**

**Do you have an example or a tutorial who could help me ?**

Comment: Will the sidebar's contents by static or dynamic?

Comment: In my idea, it should be dynamic and updated when I add a related post.

Comment: if you want proper answers for this, you need to define _what you want to be in the sidebar_. The default template already shows navigation links on the top. What do you need further than this?

That being said, your thoughts about a template included with a `$partial$` sounds reasonable.